# ColdFusion database update error

Tags: coldfusion

I get this error (see code below error):

```
Error Executing Database Query.

Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

The error occurred in 

C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 54
Called from C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 53
Called from C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 1
Called from C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 54
Called from C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 53
Called from C:\Sites\laroccaseafood\www.laroccaseafood.com\wwwroot\Admin\AdminCustomer.cfm: line 1
52 :    </CFCASE>
53 :    <CFCASE VALUE="update">
54 :        <CFUPDATE TABLENAME="Customer" DATASOURCE="#client.datasource#">
55 :        <CFQUERY NAME="GetCustomer" DATASOURCE="#client.datasource#">
56 :            Select * From Customer
```

CODE EXAMPLE:

Line 1 to 4 are as follows:

```
<CFQUERY Name="GetFaxFrequency" datasource="#client.datasource#">
    Select * From Fax_Frequency
    Order By Fax_Frequency_Id
</CFQUERY>
```

Error code derived from this code below:

```
<TR><TD VALIGN="top">
<CFSET mode_list = "add,edit,update,invalid">
    <CFIF ListContainsNoCase(mode_list, url.mode)>
    <CFIF url.mode is "invalid">
        <TABLE ALIGN="center" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="Red">
        <TR><TH COLSPAN="4">Current Customer Record</TH></TR>
    <CFELSE>
        <TABLE ALIGN="center" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR><TH COLSPAN="4">Edit Customer</TH></TR>
    </CFIF>
    <CFFORM ACTION="AdminCustomer.cfm?mode=update" METHOD="post" NAME="addCustomer">


    <CFOUTPUT>          
        <TR><TD>First Name</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.First_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="First_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter First Name">
        </TD><TD>Last Name</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.Last_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Last_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Last Name">
        </TD></TR>

        <TR><TD>Company</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.Company_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Company_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Company Name">
        </TD><TD>Fax ( 4153446789 )</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.Fax_Number#" MAXLENGTH="11" NAME="Fax_Number" REQUIRED="Yes" VALIDATE="integer" RANGE="0000000000,19999999999" MESSAGE="Enter a proper fax number ( 14153768888 )">
        </TD></TR>

        <TR><TD>User Name</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.User_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="User_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter User Name">
        </TD><TD>Password</TD><TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#GetCustomer.Password#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Password" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Password">
        </TD></TR>
    </CFOUTPUT> 

        <TR><TD>User Type</TD><TD>
        <SELECT NAME="User_Level">
        <CFLOOP LIST="Administrator,Salesperson,Customer" INDEX="User_Level">
            <CFOUTPUT>          
            <option VALUE="#User_Level#" <cfif #User_Level# is #GetCustomer.User_Level#>Selected</CFIF> >#User_Level#
            </CFOUTPUT>         
        </CFLOOP>
        </SELECT>
        </TD><TD>Account Status</TD>
        <TD>Enabled
        <INPUT TYPE="Radio" NAME="Customer_Status" VALUE="1" <cfif #GetCustomer.Customer_Status# is 1>CHECKED</cfif> >
        Disabled
        <INPUT TYPE="Radio" NAME="Customer_Status" VALUE="0" <cfif #GetCustomer.Customer_Status# is 0>CHECKED</cfif> >
        </TD></TR>

        <TR><TD NOWRAP><BR>
        Here Now <BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="here_now" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#GetCustomer.here_now#,#Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>
        Coming Soon<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="coming_soon" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#GetCustomer.coming_soon#,#Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>    
        All Items<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="all_items" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#GetCustomer.all_items#,#Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>    
        Hot List<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="hot_list" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#GetCustomer.hot_list#,#Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD></TR>
        <TR><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD></TR>       
    <CFOUTPUT>
        <TR><TD COLSPAN="4">
        <INPUT TYPE="Hidden" VALUE="#GetCustomer.Customer_Id#" NAME="Customer_Id">
    <CFIF url.mode is NOT "invalid">
        <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE=" update ">  
    </CFIF>
        </TD><TR>
    </CFOUTPUT> 
    </CFFORM>
    </TABLE>

    </CFIF>
</TD></TR>

<TR><TD ALIGN="center" VALIGN="top">
    <TABLE ALIGN="center" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0">
    <CFFORM ACTION="AdminCustomer.cfm?mode=Add" METHOD="post" NAME="addCustomer">
    <CFIF url.mode is "invalid">
    <TR><TH NOWRAP ALIGN="center">  
    <FONT CLASS="errortext">The User Name submitted already exists!
    </TH></TR>  
    <CFSET User_Name = "">
    <CFELSE>
    <CFSCRIPT>
            User_Name = "";
            Password = "";
            First_Name = "";
            Last_Name = "";
            Company_Name = "";
            First_Name = "";
            Fax_Number = "";
            Hot_list = "";
            Coming_Soon = "";
            Here_Now = "";
            All_Items = "";
    </CFSCRIPT>
    </CFIF>

    <TR><TH>Add Customer</TH></TR>
    <TR><TD>
        <TABLE ALIGN="center" CELLPADDING="2">
        <CFOUTPUT>          
        <TR><TD>First Name</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#First_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="First_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter First Name">
        </TD>
        <TD>Last Name</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#Last_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Last_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Last Name">
        </TD></TR>

        <TR><TD>Company</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#Company_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Company_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Company Name">
        </TD>
        <TD>Fax ( 14153446789 )</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#Fax_Number#" MAXLENGTH="11" NAME="Fax_Number" REQUIRED="Yes" VALIDATE="integer" RANGE="0000000000,19999999999" MESSAGE="Enter a proper fax number ( 14153768888 )">
        </TD></TR>

        <TR><TD>User Name</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#User_Name#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="User_Name" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter User Name">
        </TD>
        <TD>Password</TD>
        <TD>
        <CFINPUT TYPE="Text" SIZE="20" VALUE="#Password#" MAXLENGTH="50" NAME="Password" REQUIRED="Yes" MESSAGE="Enter Password">
        </TD></TR>
        </CFOUTPUT> 

        <TR><TD NOWRAP><BR>
        Here Now <BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="here_now" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#here_now#, #Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>
        Coming Soon<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="coming_soon" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#coming_soon#, #Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>    
        All Items<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="all_items" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#"  <CFIF #listfind(#all_items#, #Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD><TD NOWRAP><BR>    
        Hot List<BR><FONT CLASS="normaltext">
            <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetFaxFrequency">
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" NAME="hot_list" VALUE="#Fax_Frequency_Id#" <CFIF #listfind(#hot_list#, #Fax_Frequency_Id#)# is not 0>Checked</CFIF> >&nbsp;#Fax_Frequency_Desc#<BR>
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </TD></TR>
        <TR><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD><TD><BR></TD></TR>       
        <TR><TD>User Type</TD>
        <TD>
            <SELECT NAME="User_Level">
            <CFLOOP LIST="Administrator,Salesperson,Customer" INDEX="User_Level">
                <CFOUTPUT>          
                <option VALUE="#User_Level#" <cfif #User_Level# is "Customer">Selected</CFIF> >#User_Level#
                </CFOUTPUT>         
            </CFLOOP>
            </SELECT>
        </TD><TD>
        <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE=" Add Customer">  
        </TD><TR>
        </CFFORM>
        </TABLE>
        </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    </TD></TR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a few other issues .. my guess is you are using an MS Access Unicode datasource and that `Password` may be a reserved word.  If so, either rename the column (preferable) or switch to a regular `<cfquery>` and escape it with square brackets ie `[Password]`.

```
UPDATE Customer
SET    [Password] = <cfqueryparam value="#form.password#" ....>
...
```

**Update:** While I am still guessing about your database/dsn, I can confirm that `Password` is a reserved word with that driver. This simple test with two fields fails with the exact same error. Remove the `Password` field and it succeeds. That is not to say it is the *only* issue ...

```
<cfupdate tableName="Customer" formfields="first_name,password" datasource="#dsn#">
```

Comment: I can get in and add plus delete a client in the list but can not update the record once it in in DB - so password is not the issue from what I can tell - main error is line 54:
Error Executing Database Query.

Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
 
52 :  </CFCASE>
53 :  <CFCASE VALUE="update">
54 :   <CFUPDATE TABLENAME="Customer" DATASOURCE="#client.datasource#">
55 :   <CFQUERY NAME="GetCustomer" DATASOURCE="#client.datasource#">
56 :    Select * From Customer

Comment: First, what database type are you using? Is it MS Access (Unicode DSN)?

Comment: If you are also using the Unicode DSN, then you will have to rename the `Password` column OR switch to a `cfquery` UPDATE and escape the column name. See the example above.